# How to dismiss a ViewController while the navigationItem's searchBar has focus

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I updated my app to handle the new iOS 11 search behavior for search bars under the navigation bar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController;

    // Those are optional, but that's what I want my UI to look like
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
}
```

I also have a button on my view, which when tapped will dismiss the current view controller:

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is: if the searchController's searchBar has focus (ie. is the first responder) when the user taps the button, the view controller is not dismissed.

- On the first tap on the button, the searchBar loses its focus and the keyboard hides (as if `[searchBar resignFirstResponder]` had been called);
- On the second tap, the view controller is finally being dismissed.

[image]

How can I make the first tap on the button dismiss the view controller immediately (removing the searchBar's focus as a side effect)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to dismiss the view controller immediately is to use the `UISearchController` [`isActive` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618659-isactive):

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
    self.navigationItem.searchController.active = NO;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.2

```
self.searchController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
   ///
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario I have a *UITableViewController* with a search bar as overlay. The search results are in a separate *UITableViewController*. Now I wanted to dismiss the overlay while the search results are shown. @Guillaume Algis your solution worked perfectly for me as well.

Syntax in Swift 4:

```
    self.navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = false
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

All the above methods cause `updateSearchResults` to be called with an empty string.
Depending on your implementation this may lead to reloading of the tableview which may be detrimental to the user experience.

The following works around this issue for me:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, work around is:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
searchController.isActive = false
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

then you can dismiss viewController by delegate or directly.