# UISearchController UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working after filter

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, dismiss

I have a `UIViewController` that I open by presenting it. In it avec have just a `UITableView` and `UISearchController` that :

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

It works well. I can filter the `UITableView` each time the user update the `UISearchBar` field.

My `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function is like that :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The first time I select a row after filtering the `UItableView` (when the UISearchBar is focused) my `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is called but the `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` does not work. It just `resignFristResponder()` the `UISearchBar`.

Then if a select again a cell, now that the `UISearchBar` is no more focused the `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` works.

So I have to select twice a cell to see my `UIViewController` dismissed.

What is wrong with that ?

Comment: I've finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585175/how-to-dismiss-a-viewcontroller-while-the-navigationitems-searchbar-has-focus)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dismiss a ViewController while the navigationItem's searchBar has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585175/how-to-dismiss-a-viewcontroller-while-the-navigationitems-searchbar-has-focus)

Comment: I've proposed a duplicate which will link your question to where you found the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try calling dismiss on the searchController first

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    searchController.dismiss(animated: false)
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

I have just tested this and it works whether the search is active or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just Makey sure you are creating your search controller like this.

`let searchController: UISearchController = {
        let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        search.definesPresentationContext = true
        search.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        return search
    }()`

Especially this line. That solved my problem in ios 12

```
dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

Once didSelectRow method starts getting called, put this line of code to dismiss Search Controller.

```
searchController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Just revisiting this, since `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` became obsolete since iOS 12: we should now use `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dismiss the `UISearchViewController` when it is **active**.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
  if searchController.isActive {
     searchController.dismiss(animated: true) {
      // Go to next screen
    }
  } else {
    // Go to next screen
  }
}
```